# Move one header row of multiheader dataframe to a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a csv using pandas csv_reader that uses multiple rows for the headers. I am able to read in the file skip the required rows before the headers and also reset_index to not use the first column as I dont want my data to be the index. The trick is that after reading in the dataframe I need to try and perform two tasks. The top row doesn't repeat header names but is blank when it represents the last field filled in. I would like to "pivot" this header to a column leaving only the second header and filling in the respective blank cells.

an example of input would be like:

```
   a        b      
  c1 c2 c3 c1 c2 c3
1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

what I am trying to output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `stack(level=0)`, then reset your index.

```
df.stack(level=0).reset_index(level=-1).rename({'level_1': 'cNew'}, axis=1)
```

---

**Minimal Code Sample**

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']])
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(1, 5), columns=idx)
df

   a        b      
  c1 c2 c3 c1 c2 c3
1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0

df.stack(level=0).reset_index(level=-1).rename({'level_1': 'cNew'}, axis=1)

  cNew  c1  c2  c3
1    a   0   0   0
1    b   0   0   0
2    a   0   0   0
2    b   0   0   0
3    a   0   0   0
3    b   0   0   0
4    a   0   0   0
4    b   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks that worked well for the reshaping but is there also a way to infer the top level headers. In your example all three a columns and b columns are already filled in. My source only has the first and then blanks until the next header.

Comment: @labowski2944 please provide a reproducible sample of your data. I don't want to keep guessing what your input looks like because that's a waste of our time both.

Comment: the example is in the exact format I am describing. There is only a single cell that says "a" followed by 2 blank cells then "b" and two blank cells. In your solution which works fine there is actually data with a, a, a, b, b, b it doesn't actually represent the starting data with missing headers in the top header